# TransactionAttribute.REQUIRES_NEW in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I tested my ejb jpa transactions. I use Container-managed entityManager:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "ParticularUnit")
EntityManager em;
```

Such I has got transaction PersistanceContext scope and container manages each transaction.
For each instance of pooled session beans, created instance of entityManager.
When I mark bean method with @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED) and
invoke two method within, I expected then method test1 will have another PersitenceContext, but I was surprised, because it was the same.

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)

public void test(Configuration config){
        if (!em.contains(config)) {
            config = em.find(Configuration.class, config.getId());
        }
        System.out.println("********************");
        System.out.println("actiovation, em= "+ em);
        System.out.println("actiovation, config= "+ config);
        System.out.println("*********************");

        test1(config);
        test2(config);
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void test1(Configuration config){
        config = em.find(Configuration.class, config.getId());
        System.out.println("////////");
        System.out.println("requires_new"+ config);
        System.out.println("requires_new, em= "+ em);
        System.out.println("----------------");
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void test2(Configuration config){
        config = em.find(Configuration.class, config.getId());
        System.out.println("////////");
        System.out.println("required"+ config);
        System.out.println("required, em= "+ em);
        System.out.println("----------------");
    }
```

I call `test` and got this trace.

```
********************
 actiovation, em= JPATxEntityManager@54515451
 actiovation, config= com.profix.sc.db.configuration.Configuration@7f287f28
 *********************
 ////////
 requires_newcom.profix.sc.db.configuration.Configuration@7f287f28
 requires_new, em= JPATxEntityManager@54515451[PuId=SCApplication#SCApplication-ejb.jar#SCApplication, SCApplication#SCApplication-ejb.jar#PaymentConfigBean#com.profix.sc.ejb.PaymentConfigBean/em]
----------------
  ////////
    requiredcom.profix.sc.db.configuration.Configuration@7f287f28
  required, em= JPATxEntityManager@54515451[PuId=SCApplication#SCApplication-ejb.jar#SCApplication, SCApplication#SCApplication-ejb.jar#PaymentConfigBean#com.profix.sc.ejb.PaymentConfigBean/em]
```

---

Why within `test1()` persistenceContext is the same as in `test()`?

Answer (score 4):

I guess that you're not invoking a business method at all. You're invoking local call (implicit 'this') - not the EJB one.

Try doing this call by using a [business interface](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/SessionContext.html#getBusinessObject%28java.lang.Class%29).

Try changing the calls to test1() and test2() in your test() class from:

```
test1(config);
test2(config);
```

to

```
getBusinessObject(YourEJB.class).test1(config);
getBusinessObject(YourEJB.class).test2(config);
```

PS. I'm not sure about that, but the container can use proxy object for EntityManager, so try testing if you're really in the same PersistenceContext (by doing some operations rather than just calling it's reference)

Comment: I call method throw interface view. And I tried persist entity in test but not flush it, then in test1 and test2 I successfully retreived it.

Comment: @Balconsky sorry, didn't understand 'I call method throw interface view'. Are you calling the 'test()' method from outside of this EJB?

Comment: I mean, this bean implements local interface 'beanInterface' and in servlet with @EJB annotation I inject 'beanInterface' instance and then invoke its test method.

Comment: Than did you try changing the `YourEJB.class`, in my exemplary code, to your interface name and executing it?

Comment: I tried get object by getBusinessObject(YourEJB.class).test1(config); getBusinessObject(YourEJB.class).test2(config); But in this case I got another bean from pool with another entityManager certainly with another persistenceContext.

Comment: And what did you expect? Test1 is 'REQUIRES_NEW' so it SHOULD be a new transaction with new PersistenceContext. Test2 is REQUIRED so it should be the same transaction with the same PersistenceContext. If the JTA transaction is the same, the PersistenceContext is shared between components within transactions.

Comment: yes, exactly I expected, but test1 with 'REQUIRES_NEW' has the same peristanceContext. Thank you for your efforts, I present you one vote.

Comment: @Balconsky you might be interested in [this summary](http://piotrnowicki.com/2011/11/am-i-in-the-same-transaction-am-i-using-the-same-persistencecontext/) I've prepared.

Comment: I would like to ask can a container transaction consists of two requires_new? For example, methodA() call methodB() and  methodB() call methodC(), where methodB() and methodC() are declared transactions = requires_new.